# Didomi trying to add events with variables

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to add these values ​​according to what the user does but I can't figure out how to do it:

```
enum DidomiStatusType: String, Codable {
case custom = "custom"
case disableAll = "all-denied"
case enabledAll = "all-accepted"
case none = "no-gdpr" }
```

In this function I have a listener where I call the actions that the user does, the problem is that I don't know what function to put if the user has customized it and I don't know if the way I was putting it is right

```
//If the user agreed all
let didomiEventListener = EventListener()

            didomiEventListener.onNoticeClickAgree = { _ in
            if self.type == .fakeSplash {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.statusType = .enabledAll
                    self.delegate?.continueNavigation()
                }
            }
        }
```

And if the user performs another action without accepting:

```
didomiEventListener.onHideNotice = { _ in
            if self.type == .fakeSplash {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.statusType = .none
                    self.statusType = .custom
                    self.statusType = .disableAll
                    self.delegate?.continueNavigation()
                }
            }
        }
```

I was following this [documentation](https://developers.didomi.io/cmp/mobile-sdk/ios/reference/events)

Comment: Hi, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing so bad, so there's the solution:

I upgraded the Didomi version too.

First I changed my enum to only String with the params I need

```
enum DidomiUserType: String {
case custom = "custom"
case disableAll = "all-denied"
case enabledAll = "all-accepted"
case none = "no-gdpr" }
```

Then I added a Struct like this:

```
struct DidomiUserData {
var vendorEnabled: Int
var vendorDisabled: Int
var purposeEnabled: Int
var purposeDisabled: Int
var isUserConsentStatusPartial: Bool
var type: DidomiUserType = .none }
```

The next thing I did was declare a constant that is and a variable with the struct of DidomiUserData.

```
let didomiUserStatusData = Didomi.shared.getUserStatus()
var didomiUserData = DidomiUserData(and the struct)
```

Finally only have to do an if-if-else.